# String manipulation in polars

Tags: python, string, data-manipulation, python-polars

I have a record in polars which has no header so far. This header should refer to the first row of the record. Before I instantiate this row as header, I want to manipulate the entries.

```
        import polars as pl
        # Creating a dictionary with the data
        data = {
            "Column_1": ["ID", 4, 4, 4, 4],
            "Column_2": ["LocalValue", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
            "Column_3": ["Data\nField", "Q", "R", "S", "T"],
            "Column_4": [None, None, None, None, None],
            "Column_5": ["Global Value", "G", "H", "I", "J"],
        }
        # Creating the dataframe
        table = pl.DataFrame(data)
        print(table)
    
    shape: (5, 5)
    ┌──────────┬────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────────┐
    │ Column_1 ┆ Column_2   ┆ Column_3 ┆ Column_4 ┆ Column_5     │
    │ ---      ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---          │
    │ str      ┆ str        ┆ str      ┆ f64      ┆ str          │
    ╞══════════╪════════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════════╡
    │ ID       ┆ LocalValue ┆ Data     ┆ null     ┆ Global Value │
    │          ┆            ┆ Field    ┆          ┆              │
    │ null     ┆ B          ┆ Q        ┆ null     ┆ G            │
    │ null     ┆ C          ┆ R        ┆ null     ┆ H            │
    │ null     ┆ D          ┆ S        ┆ null     ┆ I            │
    │ null     ┆ E          ┆ T        ┆ null     ┆ J            │
    └──────────┴────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────────┘
```

First, I want to replace line breaks and spaces between words with an underscore. Furthermore I want to fill Camel Cases with an underscore (e.g. TestTest -> Test_Test). Finally, all entries should be lowercase. For this I wrote the following function:

```
def clean_dataframe_columns(df):
    header = list(df.head(1).transpose().to_series())
    cleaned_headers = []
    for entry in header:
        if entry:
            entry = (
                entry.replace("\n", "_")
                .replace("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", "_")
                .replace("\s", "_")
                .to_lowercase()
            )
        else:
            entry = "no_column"
        cleaned_headers.append(entry)
    df.columns = cleaned_headers
    return df
```

Unfortunately I have the following error. What am I doing wrong?

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 1
----> 1 df1 = clean_dataframe_columns(df)

Cell In[12], line 7, in clean_dataframe_columns(df)
      4 for entry in header:
      5     if entry:
      6         entry = (
----> 7             entry.str.replace("\n", "_")
      8             .replace("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", "_")
      9             .replace("\s", "_")
     10             .to_lowercase()
     11         )
     12     else:
     13         entry = "no_column"

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

The goal should be this dataframe:

```
shape: (4, 5)
┌─────┬─────────────┬────────────┬───────────┬──────────────┐
│ id  ┆ local_value ┆ data_field ┆ no_column ┆ global_value │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---          │
│ i64 ┆ str         ┆ str        ┆ f64       ┆ str          │
╞═════╪═════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╡
│ 4   ┆ B           ┆ Q          ┆ null      ┆ G            │
│ 4   ┆ C           ┆ R          ┆ null      ┆ H            │
│ 4   ┆ D           ┆ S          ┆ null      ┆ I            │
│ 4   ┆ E           ┆ T          ┆ null      ┆ J            │
└─────┴─────────────┴────────────┴───────────┴──────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it on my own with this approach:

```
def clean_select_columns(self, df: pl.DataFrame) -> pl.DataFrame:
    """
    Clean columns from a dataframe.

    :param df: input Dataframe
    :return: Dataframe with cleaned columns

    The function takes a loaded Dataframe and performs the following operations:

        Transposes the first row of the dataframe to get the header
        Selects the required columns defined in the list required_columns
        Cleans the header names by:
            1. Replacing special characters with underscores
            2. Converting CamelCase strings to snake_case strings
            3. Converting all columns to lowercase
            4. Naming columns with no names as "no_column_X", where X is a unique integer
            5. Returns the cleaned dataframe.
    """
    header = list(df.head(1).transpose().to_series())
    cleaned_headers = []
    i = 0
    for entry in header:
        if entry:
            entry = (
                re.sub(r"(?i)([\n ?])", "",
                re.sub(r"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])", "_", entry))
                .lower()
            )
        else:
            entry = f"no_column_{i}"
        cleaned_headers.append(entry)
        i += 1
    df.columns = cleaned_headers
    return df
```

Answer (score 2):

Here `for entry in header:` you iterate over *python strings*, so you should use corresponding methods (like `.lower()` instead of `.to_lowercase()`).

---

Rewritten sol-n:

```py
import re

def get_cols(raw_col):
    if raw_col is None: return "no_column"
    raw_col = re.sub("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", "_", raw_col)
    return raw_col.replace("\n", "_").replace(" ", "_").lower()


def clean_dataframe_columns(df):
    raw_cols = table.head(1).transpose().to_series().to_list()

    return df.rename({
        col: get_cols(raw_col) for col, raw_col in zip(df.columns, raw_cols)
    }).slice(1).with_column(pl.col("id").fill_null(4).cast(pl.Int32))
```

```
┌─────┬─────────────┬────────────┬───────────┬──────────────┐
│ id  ┆ local_value ┆ data_field ┆ no_column ┆ global_value │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---          │
│ str ┆ str         ┆ str        ┆ f64       ┆ str          │
╞═════╪═════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╡
│ 4   ┆ B           ┆ Q          ┆ null      ┆ G            │
│ 4   ┆ C           ┆ R          ┆ null      ┆ H            │
│ 4   ┆ D           ┆ S          ┆ null      ┆ I            │
│ 4   ┆ E           ┆ T          ┆ null      ┆ J            │
└─────┴─────────────┴────────────┴───────────┴──────────────┘
```